# Finding a Möbius Transformation along a particular contour

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $C$ be the circle with center $0$ and radius $1$. Find a Möbius transformation which transforms $C$ onto $C$ and transforms $0$ to $1/2$.

Notes: consider $h(z)= az+\dfrac{b}{c}z+d$ then $h(0) = 1/2$ so $2b = d$. Check this works by confirming $\left|h(z)\right| = 1$ when $\left|z\right| = 1$ (along the contour $C$) so that

\begin{equation}
\left|az+b\right|^{2} = \left|cz+2b\right|^2
\end{equation}

when

\begin{equation}
\left|z\right| = 1 \rightarrow \left|a\right|^{2}\left|z\right|^2+2\Re(a\bar{b}z + \left|b\right|^2) = \left|c\right|^{2}\left|z\right|^2+4\Re((\bar{b}cz) + 4\left|b\right|^2)
\end{equation}

The problem is I cannot get them equal, so I'm not sure if this method will satisfy.

I also tried another method considering the case $i \cdot \dfrac{z+i}{z-i}$ with formula $h(z)=f^{-1}(rf(z))$ this yielded an imaginary answer for $r$ which is wrong.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: sorry about that. thank you.

Comment: Let $h(0)=1/2, h(1)=1, h(-1)=-1$, and I think it should work.

Comment: thank you i will see where this gets me.